# Android WebView: Video Playing issues

Tags: android, android-webview

NOTE: WORKS FINE ON 4.1.2 (Samsung galavy tab 2), Does not work on 4.1.1

I am trying to play a video inside a webview, 
as long as I am using a url from the web as source of the video, it works fine.

```
<source src="http://0800200c9a66-content-preview.testvideo.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

```
    function playVideo() {
var video = document.getElementById("video");

video.focus();
video.load(); //have to load first, then to play
video.play();
```

The problem comes when I change the source to a video on the sd card like
      src="file:////storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.player/files/content_path/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">

When I give a local file as the source, then only the audio plays and the video shows a black screen. Any idea how to fix this?

p.s. the video url in the above code is not a real one, it is just an example of my code. The real url works fine.
NOTE: WORKS FINE ON 4.1.2 (Samsung galavy tab 2), Does not work on 4.1.1